Ports 25 and 465 are blocked automatically after reboot
I have an Ubuntu 20.04.6 TLS server with ISPConfig Version: 3.2 and many websites installed. I set up Postfix with an SMTP relay service (Mailgun). After I reboot my server, the SMTP-Server stops working and ports 25 and 465 are not reachable. When trying to send an email from Roundcube, I get the following error: SMTP Error (-1): Connection to server failed.
I run service postfix status and this is the output:
● postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Mon 2024-05-06 03:35:54 -04; 45min ago
    Process: 1956 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1956 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

may 06 03:35:54 servidor1 systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
may 06 03:35:54 servidor1 systemd[1]: Finished Postfix Mail Transport Agent.

Then if I restart postfix and works again. Why is that?
